# componentsSeparatedByString can't compare strings with values

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string

i'm having this problem when i'm separating a string into an array using the componentsSeparatedByString function in xcode.

so i create an array from this string:

```
theDataObject.stringstick = @"1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0";

stickerarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[theDataObject.stringstick componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
```

so in my mind i expect:

```
stickerarray = {@"1",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"1",@"0",@"1",@"1",@"1",@"0",@"0",@"0"}
```

so when i chuck it through an if statement to check if an index is = 1

```
for ( int n = 0; n <= 15; n++) {
    if ([stickerarray objectAtIndex:n] == @"1") {
        NSLog(@"this works %i", n);
    } else {
                NSLog(@"this did not work on %@", [stickerarray objectAtIndex:n]);
    }
}
```

this is what i get:

```
 this did not work on 1
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 1
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 1
 this did not work on 1
 this did not work on 1
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 0
 this did not work on 0
```

I was amazed when i found this didn't work so i tried applying some queries:

```
NSLog(@"ns array value of %@",[stickerarray objectAtIndex:2] );
ns array value of 0

NSLog(@"%@", stickerarray);
(
1,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
1,
0,
1,
1,
1,
0,
0,
0
```

)

```
NSLog(@"%@", theDataObject.stringstick);
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

I suspect that it's the @"1" when i'm comparing it inside the if statement.  Be a great help if you can fix this for me.  Thanks :)

Comment: This is not how you compare strings `[stickerarray objectAtIndex:n] == @"1"`. This will compare the pointer addresses. What you need to do it use the correct method `[[stickerarray objectAtIndex:n] isEqualToString:@"1"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of componentsSeparatedByString is probably working, but your test is flawed. In objective-c you need to use NSString's isEqualToString. "==" compares the pointers of the two strings and would only be equal if they were pointing to the same instance of the string. You should use something more like:

```
[item isEqualToString:@"1"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Changed it to: 
        if ([[stickerarray objectAtIndex:n]isEqualToString:@"1"] ) 
and worked instantly, thanks for answering so fast.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't comparing strings correctly..

```
for ( int n = 0; n <= 15; n++) {
    if ([[stickerarray objectAtIndex:n] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        NSLog(@"this works %i", n);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"this did not work on %@", [stickerarray objectAtIndex:n]);
    }
}
```

extra advice.. you should also probably loop through your array differently. (A block would be fastest)

```
for (id obj in stickerarry){
//do stuff with obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator `==` compares two *values* - integers, floats, references etc. When you write:

```
[stickerarray objectAtIndex:n] == @"1"
```

You are asking whether the *reference* returned by `objectAtIndex:` is equal to the reference returned by the literal expression `@"1"`, which is very unlikely to be either true or what you wish.

To compare whether to object instances represent the same value you use the method `isEqual:`:

```
[[stickerarray objectAtIndex:n] isEqual:@"1"]
```

That will work for any kind of objects, for strings it is usually more common to use `isEqualToString:` - it produces exactly the same answer but is a little faster.

Comment: thanks again, same answer as the other guy.  Very helpful, thanks :)